# rest api update resource with partial json

Tags: json, rest, patch, put

Want to understand good practice to design REST API

If a resource needs to be update partially, which is better? PUT or PATCH

Please advice if my understanding is correct

**POST** - to persist Customer with 2 address

```
{"custId":"1", "name":"Rocky", 
"address":[{"id":"1","zip":"1234"}, 
{"id":"2","zip":"12345"}]
}
```

Now to **update** zip code for address id 1

**PUT** - full JSON is a requirement to be sent to REST API ?

```
{"custId":"1", "name":"Rocky", 
"address":[{"id":"1","zip":"9876"}, 
{"id":"2","zip":"12345"}]
}
```

**PATCH** - partial (or full) JSON can be sent to REST API ?

```
{"custId":"1", "name":"Rocky", 
"address":[{"id":"1","zip":"9876"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding seems basically correct, but your example hints at a possible problem in your thinking. The document you're talking about is actually a customer with a collection of addresses. Each address could be seen as a separate document, because it has an ID. Therefore, your api should allow you to update a single address without updating a customer. What you're missing in your example is the URI for the resources. So, you should have something like `customer/1` to identify the customer and maybe something like `customer/1/address/1` to identify the address.

Comment: thanks, yes I forgot to mention. But then I have another question - if suppose I want to update only one property(lastN) of customer {id:1,firstN:fb,lastN:ln,dept:201,region:NA}, then one should send only {id:1,lastN:newLn} with PATCH or {id:1,firstN:fb,lastN:newLn,dept:201,region:NA} with PUT