# PUT vs PATCH with example

Tags: json, rest, api

Question on best practice on REST API design

Suppose I want to update only one property(lastN) of customer

```
{id:1,firstN:fb,lastN:ln,dept:201,region:NA}
```

then one can/should send
`{id:1,lastN:newLn}` with PATCH/PUT or both  ?
`{id:1,firstN:fb,lastN:newLn,dept:201,region:NA}` with PUT/PATCH or both ?

I have already asked similar(not same) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600470/rest-api-update-resource-with-partial-json/40600641#40600641), and want to know the answer for this also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PUT should be used to update the whole resource. For partial updates PATCH is the correct verb.

However, PATCH is not a straight replacement for PUT. If you only want to send partial properties to add/update, the content type "application/merge-patch+json" should be used. The body would only contain modified properties.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396

```
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{firstN:newFn,region:null,middleName:newMn}
```

Another, more descriptive alternative is to use JSON Patch document that actually defines operations.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-3

```
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
   { "op": "add", "path": "/middleName", "value": newMn },
   { "op": "remove", "path": "/region" },
   { "op": "replace", "path": "/firstN", "value": newFn },
]
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like diff things to be done with PATCH. Hope PUT is also acceptable as good design to update partial changes by sending the full json again